# mysql only compares first numerical part of string to int column in where

Tags: mysql

This is more a "why" or "any pointers to documentations" question.

Today I realised that a comparison in WHERE clause takes only the first numerical part of the string if compared to an INT column. (My own conclusion)

For example:

`SELECT * FROM companies c WHERE id = '817m5'`

will still return companies with id = 817.

It does make sense but I'm failing to find this documented anywhere to see if my conclusion is correct and if there are additional things to know about this exact behaviour. `WHERE`, INT type, comparison documentation? Where? How is it called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the comparison:

```
WHERE id = '817m5'
```

and `id` is an integer.

So, MySQL has to compare an integer to a string.  Well, it can't do that directly.  It either has to convert the string to a number or the number to the string.  MySQL converts the string to a number, which it does by converting the leading numeric characters.  So, the `'817m5'` becomes `817`.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) is the exact quote:

> To cast a string to a numeric value in numeric context, you normally
>   do not have to do anything other than to use the string value as
>   though it were a number:

```
mysql> SELECT 1+'1'; -> 2
```